# How to optimize the speed of DELETE in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table Words and stores English words. The columns are ( id, word, type, explaination, example ).

These words were crawled from vocabulary.com and there are lots of repeated rows in my table. The number of rows in Words table is 800k+, so I want to delete some repeated rows.
In my though,

Step 1: Create a table called "words_temp" and insert all repeated word in table "words" into "words_temp";

Step 2: Delete rows which column "word" in table "word_temp";

Step 3: Merge two tables;

Following are my clauses:
Step 1:

```
INSERT INTO words_tmp 
   (SELECT * 
       FROM words 
       GROUP BY word 
       HAVING COUNT(word) > 1 );
```

Step 2:

```
DELETE FROM words 
   WHERE word in (SELECT word FROM words_tmp);
```

but the speed of "Step 2" is very slow, I have waited for the execute for 10 minutes but nothing happen. Can anybody kindly tell me how to optimize my SQL clauses?

Comment: You need to tell us _which_ of the duplicate rows should be preserved.  Your current deletion logic would delete _all_ duplicate rows.

Comment: ow! . i think this design of database is so very heavy . try to change a design instead of some words. try to explore `"JOIN"`

Comment: yeah, my first step is create a table "words_tmp",  copy all the repeated rows into "words_temp" with clause " INSERT INTO words_tmp (SELECT * FROM words GROUP BY word HAVING COUNT(word)>1);" and then delete all the rows from table "words" where "word" in table "words_tmp", finally I want to combine rows in "words" and "words_temp".

Comment: Indeed I do want to delete all duplicate rows from table "word", but I have stored repeated rows in table "words_temp", after the deletion I can insert all the rows in table "words_tmp" into table "words". I thought that will satisfy my demand.

Comment: What are the indexes and constrains on your table?

Comment: My table only have id(primary key), no other indexes

Comment: What determines a "duplicate" that needs to be deleted?  Same word?  Entire row is same?  Something else?

Comment: With no index on `word`, how does someone use the table??

Answer (score 4):

You can try to delete them using:

```
delete w
    from words w join
         (select w.word, min(w.id) as min_id
          from words w
          group by w.word
         ) ww
         on w.word = ww.word and w.id > ww.min_id;
```

This assumes that `id` is unique.  You can speed this up a bit with an index on `words(word, id)`.

That said, the most efficient method is often to empty the table and repopulate it:

```
create table temp_words as
    select w.*
    from words w
    where w.id > (select min(w2.id) from words w2 where w2.word = w.word);
```

Then, truncate the original table and re-insert (be sure you have stashed a copy of the original table somewhere before trying this!):

```
truncate table words;

insert into words
    select w.*
    from temp_words;
```

Inserts have much less locking and logging than `delete`s, so this often speeds up such processes.

Comment: Thank you, but I tried your second block of code, it was very slow and I have been waiting for it for 30 minutes.

Comment: @FriWant . . . Do you have the recommended index?

Answer (score 1):

If you have enough time for experiments try to do this

`insert into words_tmp (select distinct * from words)`

Now you have in table words_tmp only words without duplicates

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to approach this that come to mind:

If there are rather few duplicates (say no more than 5% of the rows), then go through the rows sequentially and see whether they have another match in the table.

```
delete from words
where exists
(
  select *
  from words other
  where other.word = words.word
  and others.id < word.id
);
```

You should provide an index on word and id for this:

```
create index idx_words on words(word, id);
```

If on the other hand there are many duplicates (say 20% of the rows), then create a table with the unique rows, dismiss your original table and use the new one instead.

```
create table tmp as select distinct * from words;
drop table words;
rename table tmp to words;
```